# Android Emulator boot

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm starting android development from just three days, I have downloaded the SDK and install the platform and define the emulator, but it takes a lot of time to boot every time I run the application

Is there a way to run the emulator once and then run the application and to be updated on the emulator without closing it and re-opening it again

I'm using eclipse classic please any one try to help

Comment: just don't close the emulator? running the application from eclipse again should detect an already running emulator and update the installed app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to close your emulator every time. Assuming you are using eclipse--> Right click on project-->Run-->Android application, if any changes, those will be deployed. Otherwise same screen will showup.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just hit "Run" again, it will be reinstalled automatically if you changed code, otherwise you will see a message like "brought to front".

I recommend to not stop the emulator as long as you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I usually just leave it open and launching the program from Eclipse updates the program in the emulator and launches it.

One weird thing is that the first time I launch it I get an error from Eclipse telling me that it has not been able to connect to the emulator, and the next time I launch the application a new emulator is launched. Usually I just close the first emulator,  launch it again and then it works as it should.